# Matrix Inversion of Banded Sparse Matrix using SciPy

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-inverse

I am trying to solve the inverse of a banded sparse matrix in the most efficient way so that I can incorporate this in my real-time system. I am generating sparse-banded matrices which represent a convolution operation. Currently, I am using `spsolve` from `scipy.sparse.linalg` library. I found that there is a better way by using `solve_banded` from the `scipy.linalg` library. However, `solve_banded` requires `(l,u)` which is the number of non-zero lower and upper diagonals and `ab` which `(l + u + 1, M)` array like banded matrix. I am not sure how to convert my code so that I can use `solve_banded`. Any help with this regard is highly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg
import math
import time

from scipy.sparse import spdiags
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve


def ABC(deg, fc, N):
    r"""Generate sparse-banded matrices
    """

    omc = 2*math.pi*fc
    t = ((1-math.cos(omc))/(1+math.cos(omc)))**deg

    p = 1
    for k in np.arange(deg):
        p = np.convolve(p,np.array([-1,1]),'full')
    P = spdiags(np.kron(p,np.ones((N,1))).T, np.arange(deg+1), N-deg, N)
    B = P.T.dot(P)

    q = np.sqrt(t)
    for k in np.arange(deg):
        q = np.convolve(q,np.array([1,1]),'full')
    Q = spdiags(np.kron(q,np.ones((N,1))).T, np.arange(deg+1), N-deg, N)

    C = Q.T.dot(Q)
    A = B + C

    return A,B,C

if __name__ == '__main__':

    mu = 0.1
    deg = 3
    wc = 0.1

    for i in np.arange(1,7,1):

        # some dense random vector
        x = np.random.rand(10**i,1)
        # generate sparse banded matrices
        A,_,C = ABC(deg, wc, 10**i)
        # another banded matrix
        G = mu*A.dot(A.T) + C.dot(C.T)

        # SCIPY SPSOLVE
        st = time.time()
        y = spsolve(G,x)
        et = time.time()
        print("SCIPY SPSOLVE: N = ", 10**i, "Time taken: ", et-st)
```

Results

```
SCIPY SPSOLVE: N =  10 Time taken:  0.0
SCIPY SPSOLVE: N =  100 Time taken:  0.0
SCIPY SPSOLVE: N =  1000 Time taken:  0.015689611434936523
SCIPY SPSOLVE: N =  10000 Time taken:  0.020943641662597656
SCIPY SPSOLVE: N =  100000 Time taken:  0.16722917556762695
SCIPY SPSOLVE: N =  1000000 Time taken:  1.7254831790924072
```

Comment: At a first glance, the `ab` matrix that `solve_banded` wants looks a lot like the `.data` attribute of a `scipy.dia_matrix` format.  Both define the diagonals as a padded rectangular array (the alternative being the ragged list that `sparse.diags` accepts).

Comment: Let me look into it. Also, it appears that `spsolve` does not give the right solution for the inverse problem. I checked the solution with `np.linalg.inv` and the error seems to be huge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it using `solveh_banded` from the `scipy` library. Very fast matrix inversion technique for extremely large sparse-banded matrices when the matrix is symmetric and positive definite banded matrix.

```
from scipy.linalg import solveh_banded

def sp_inv(A, x):

    A = A.toarray()
    N = np.shape(A)[0]
    D = np.count_nonzero(A[0,:])
    ab = np.zeros((D,N))
    for i in np.arange(1,D):
        ab[i,:] = np.concatenate((np.diag(A,k=i),np.zeros(i,)),axis=None)
    ab[0,:] = np.diag(A,k=0)
    y = solveh_banded(ab,x,lower=True)
    return y
```